# Using strings when specifying a key in an object's key-value pair

Tags: javascript, object, syntax, language-specifications

When specifying a key in an object's key-value pair (using the notation below) the interpreter (apparently) allows the use of strings:

```
var x = { 'color': '#fff' };
```

However specifying a key dinamically using a function (that returns a string) is not allowed:

```
function s()
{
    return 'color';
}

var x = { s(): '#fff' };
```

I guess strings, when using that notation, must be static values.

However I cannot find JavaScript language specifications regarding that...

Comment: js does not have associative array

Comment: Key expects a static value cannot be dynamic. This might be a reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_object_initializers) (I highlight with bold):

> The syntax for an object using an object initializer is:
>
> ```
> var obj = { property_1:   value_1,   // property_# may be an identifier...
>             2:            value_2,   // or a number...
>             // ...,
>             "property n": value_n }; // or a string
> ```
>
> where obj is the name of the new object, each property_*i* is an identifier (**either a name, a number, or a string literal**), and each value_*i* is an expression whose value is assigned to the property_*i*.

So in this literal notation it is not allowed to evaluate expressions, e.g. via function calls to determine the property identifiers.

In the [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5) it is more formally put:

> *PropertyName:*
>
> - *IdentifierName*
> - *StringLiteral*
> - *NumericLiteral*

### ECMAScript 2015

With ECMAScript 2015 more becomes possible as explained in [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

> Starting with ECMAScript 2015, the object initializer syntax also supports computed property names. That allows you to put an expression in brackets [ ], that will be computed as the property name.
>
> ```
> // Computed property names (ES6)
> var i = 0;
> var a = {
>   ["foo" + ++i]: i,
>   ["foo" + ++i]: i,
>   ["foo" + ++i]: i
> };
> ```

The formal definition in the [ECMAScript 2015 Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object-initializer) has:

> *PropertyName:*
>
> - *LiteralPropertyName*
> - *ComputedPropertyName*
>
> *ComputedPropertyName:*
>
> - [ *AssignmentExpression* ]

So with ES6 you would rewrite your example like this:

```
function s()
{
    return 'color';
}

var x = { [s()]: '#fff' };
```

Answer (score 4):

In this case you should use this method:

```
var x = {};
x[s()] = "#fff";
x[foo()] = "#000";
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I figured out I could do this. What I don't understand is the reason why the form I used is incorrect syntax (and I'm looking for js official specs. regarding that)

Answer (score 0):

"Associative arrays" do not exist in Javascript. You're probably referring to Objects. This is a pretty common mistake when learning JS.

An **Object** can be initialized using { }, or with the **new** operator like so :

```
var x = {};
var y = {foo : 'bar'};
var z = new Object();
```

When accessing an object properties, you can either use the . operator, or brackets.

```
var somevalue = y.foo;   // 'bar'
var someother = y['foo'] // 'bar'
```

In your current situation, you'd want something like that :

```
var x = new Object();  // or {}
x[s()] = "#fff";
```

**Object type**

If you check the **type** of x, it will return 'object'.

```
var typeOfX = typeof x;  // 'object'
```